# Why buffer contain more data when use fread function (C programming)

Tags: c

I wrote a program that copy content from a file to another but when I used fread() to read data from a file and put into buffer it turn out it have more data than the text file

**Here's my code**

```
  char *buffer;
  int size;
  FILE *fp1;
  fp1 = fopen(src, "r");
  if (fp1 == NULL) {
    err = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror( err ));
    return 0;
  }else{
    fseek(fp1, 0, SEEK_END); 
    size = ftell(fp1);
    buffer = (char *) malloc(size +1 );
    printf("data in Buffer : %s\n",buffer);
    printf("size : %d\n",size);
    fseek(fp1, 0, SEEK_SET); 
    fread(buffer,size,1,fp1);
    strcat(buffer,"\0");   
    printf("data in Buffer after fread(): %s\n",buffer);
    int a = strlen(buffer);
    printf("strlen in Buffer : %d\n",a);
    fclose(fp1);
  }
  FILE *fp2;
  fp2 = fopen("disk1.img", "a");
  if (fp2 == NULL) {
    err = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror( err ));
  }else{
    rewind(fp2);
    printf("data in Buffer before write to destination : %s\n",buffer);
    fclose(fp2);
  }
```

**source file contain**

> test kub test 
>  ah hahaha 5

**Result**

> data in Buffer : � 
> size : 26 
> data in Buffer after fread(): test kub test 
> ah hahaha 5 
> U* 
> strlen in Buffer : 30 
> data in Buffer before write to destination : test kub test 
> ah hahaha 5 
> U*

The file size is 26 bytes I specify 26 bytes in fread() but in turns out buffer contain 30 characters

I use fread() because I have to write data in specific position in destination file also I added "\0" after fread() because I though it could help but it didn't work

**This is second time I face this problem.First time I specific amount of byte when read data from buffer to solve this problem but now I want to know
Why buffer keep more data than the source file and How to fix it.

**--------------------Update----------------------------** 
I read all comment then 
I followed user2225104 suggestion and It worked ! 
I replaced strcat(buffer,"\0"); with buffer[size] = '\0'; 
Thank you all for your answer it makes me know c programming better.

**Result**

> data in Buffer : 0u 
> size : 26 
> data in Buffer after fread(): test kub test 
> ah hahaha 5
>
> strlen in Buffer : 26 
> data in Buffer before write to destination : test kub test 
> ah hahaha 5

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall | Wextra -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`). The why is probably implementation specific (depends upon compiler, libc, file system, operating system). Use an hexdumper to understand the file content. I guess you have some newliine and perhaps other EOL characters.

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behavior. `strcat(buffer,"\0");` - expects your string is already terminated; it isn't (that you know, anyway). Replace that with `buffer[size] = 0;` (or similar). And in general, *please* make it a habit of checking your result codes.

Comment: Would also replace the ``strcat(...)`` with ``buffer[size] = '\0';``.

Comment: @WhozCraig So you are the one checking return values of printf? The one (and I mean ONE) they added those return values for? :)

Comment: Don't assume that buffer[] contains all 0s. It won't. C doesn't initialize variables. So the value it contains is whatever voltage levels happen to be in RAM at the location it is allocated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your attempt to 0-terminate and turn the block of chars into a c-string.

```
strcat(buffer,"\0");
```

only works if the first string is already 0-terminated. If it were, you would not need it. As you say yourself, your supposed string length is larger than your buffer. So you read some random 0 value behind your buffers end and then overwrite memory 1 byte behind it with your strcat() operation.

```
buffer[size] = '\0';
```

This way to do it does not assume buffer is a 0-terminated string and will not hamper with memory outside buffer.

On a side note, malloc() can return NULL. Best make it a habit to ALWAYS check the results of heap operation functions, just as checking results on file operations (e.g. fopen()). Basically anything which can go wrong at run-time and is not an invariant should be checked.

Answer (score 1):

There's two kinds of strings in the programming world:

- the Pascal kind of string (used by managed languages like C# and Java), where the size of the string is stored as an integer separately
- the C kind of strings, where the size is indicated by a terminating "special" character

There's pros and cons for each of them, but the most important thing is that C style strings can't hold binary data -- the terminating character chosen by C is a valid character in a file (obviously).

So instead you emulate Pascal strings  and call them "buffers", basically vectors of characters of some kind, with the size stored manually. You can see it in your `malloc` call, and again in your `fread`. Then you sort of black out and forget you wrote it and stop using it, but the size is still there, it's not part of the string.

Instead of printing it with `printf` (which expects null terminated C strings), you should use a character buffer function like `fwrite` to write it, and give it the size as an argument. Instead you're printing memory past what you allocated (since it doesn't end with `0`), buffer overruning yourself. Generally hackers don't need your help, if they put their mind to it, they'll do it themselves :)

As a side note, you don't need `size+1` characters -- there's no terminator as explained.

Comment: "text" streams refer to new line translations, not null characters. You can obviously pretend it's a C string (`buffer[size]=0;`) if you know there's no null characters, but there's no reason. You have your data and your size, just use em together!

Comment: Yes. But then he can as well assume that he got a string and can 0-terminate it. Unicode byte-ordermarks and other stuff not taken into account ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's because your code is invalid.

```
fread(buffer,size,1,fp1);
```

Here you are ignoring the count returned by `fread()`, which tells you how many bytes have just been read into the buffer.

```
strcat(buffer,"\0");
```

Here you are pointlessly appending a null character after the first null character in the buffer. Remove it.

```
printf("data in Buffer after fread(): %s\n",buffer);
```

Here again you are ignoring the count. Assuming you used `int count = fread(...)`, this line should be

```
printf("data in Buffer after fread(): %.*s\n",count,buffer);
```

Then:

```
int a = strlen(buffer);
```

This line is pointless. You shouldn't assume that I/O operations result in null-terminated C strings. There's nothing anywhere that guarantees that. Instead, you should use the `count` again. So

```
printf("strlen in Buffer : %d\n",a);
```

should be

```
printf("byte count in Buffer : %d\n",count);
```